# Can't play H264 video created with ffmpeg libx264 library with Maui Community MediaElement

Tags: maui, maui-community-toolkit, maui-windows

In my .NET MAUI project I want to play a video with the Maui Community Toolkit MediaElement that I've created with ffmpeg.

Video's that I've created with the following arguments (using the mpeg4 codec) can be played without any issue with the MediaElement:

```
ffmpeg -framerate {preferredFrameRate} -i {OutputImgPath} -c:v mpeg4 -r {preferredFrameRate} {OutputVideoPath}
```

However, I prefer to use the ffmpeg libx264 library for better quality;

```
ffmpeg -framerate {preferredFrameRate} -i {OutputImgPath} -c:v libx264 -r {preferredFrameRate} {OutputVideoPath}
```

Video's that I've created with libx264 in ffmpeg cannot be played with MediaElement.
The MediaElement displays the error: Video could not be decoded.

[image]

I can play the video in VLC without issue. The video contains no sound. If I check the codec information in VLC I can see the following info:

[image]

I'm not sure if this is a limitation of the MediaElement or something else. It's not a big dealbreaker for me to use another codec, however, I was curious if there was a way to play video's that support more codecs in .NET Maui. Thank you for your help.I'm using CommunityToolkit.Maui.MediaElement 3.1.0.

Comment: I believe that `MediaElement` just uses the underlying platform media player, unlike VLC which actually contains custom codecs.  You could look at the `MediaElement` source to confirm

Comment: Thank you. You're correct, I can't play the video with Windows Media Player either. I'll stick to the mpeg4 codec.